# Why the email is sent and the validation errors are dont appear? (if the user dont fill the subject and message fields)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page that has a select menu so that a user can select if he wants to send a email to:

- all participants of a conference
- to all participants registered in a specific registration type of the conference
- to a specific participant registered in a conference

But its not working properly.

**Issue:**

If the user select that he wants to send a email to all participants and dont field the subject and message fields it appears "Notification sent with success", however it should appear two validation errors saying that the subject and messge fields are required. Do you know why is not working like that?

Same issue if the user select that he wants to send an email to all participants registered in a specific registration type of the conference and also dont fill the subject and message fields. Instead of appear the validation errors it appears "Notification sent with success".

Same issue if the user select that hew ants to send a email for a specific participant registered in a conference and introduce the email of the user to which wants to send the email and dont fill the subject and message fields. Instead of appear the validation errors it appears "Notification sent with success".

Full NotificationController:

```
class NotificationController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id){

        $conference = Conference::find($id);
        $registrationType = RegistrationType::where('conference_id', $id)->get();


        return view('notifications.index')->with('conference', $conference)->with('registrationType', $registrationType);
    }

    public function send(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $conference = Conference::find($id);

        $message = $request->message;
        $subject = $request->subject;
        $emails = [];

        if($request->send_to == "participant"){
            $this->validate(request(), $this->participantRules($id));

            $emails = User::whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use($id) {
                $query->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
            })->where('email', $request->email)->pluck('email');
        }else if($request->send_to == "all"){
            $emails = User::whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use($id) {
                $query->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
            })->pluck('email');
        }else{
            $emails = User::whereHas('registrations.participants.registration_type', function ($query) use ($id, $request) {
                $query->where('id', '=', $request->send_to)
                    ->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
            })->whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use ($id) {
                $query->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
            })->pluck('email');

        }

        if(count($emails) > 0) {
            $this->sendNotification($emails, $conference, $request);
            Session::flash('success', 'Notification sent with success.');
            return redirect()->back();
        }else{
            Session::flash('no_participants', 'The participant(s) are not registered in the conference.');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }

    protected function participantRules($conferenceID){
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email'
        ];
    }

    protected function sendNotification($emails, $conference, $request){
        foreach ($emails as $userEmail) {
            Mail::to($userEmail)->send(new Notification($conference, $request->message, $request->subject));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation isn't working because **you only validate the email field** in the participantRules method (by the way, the $id parameter is useless (not used) here).
**Also, you only call this method when send_to is equal to "participant"**.

```
protected function participantRules($conferenceID){
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ];
}
```

If you want to also validate the subject and message field, you have to explicitly write the rules about them. For instance, it could be:

```
protected function participantRules($conferenceID){
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'subject' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

This way, the subject and message field will also be required. Additionally, you could pass a third parameter - an array - to override the default messages.

```
$messages = [
    'email.email' => 'Your email is invalid',
    'email.required' => 'You must enter an email address',
    'subject.required' => 'You must enter a subject'
];
$this->validate(request(), $this->participantRules($id), $messages);
```

To make the validation in a cleaner way, you should use a [form request validation class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation) instead of doing inline validation, in order to keep your code well structured. Also, the list of validation rules can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#available-validation-rules).

You can easily make the email field required only if send_to is equal to participant (if that's what you want to do of course).

To achieve that, just change the participantRules method like that:

```
protected function participantRules($conferenceID){
    return [
        'email' => 'required_if:send_to,participant|email|nullable',
        'subject' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

It should now make the email field required ONLY IF send_to == 'participant'. The nullable rule permits the field to be empty in case send_to != 'participant'. If you omit it, an empty field will not pass the email validation rule (because it'll not be a valid email address).

Comment: Thanks, but also dont works with "protected function participantRules($conferenceID){
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'subject' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required'
    ];
}". If the user select for example that wants to send a notification for all participants and click "Send" and dont fill the subject and message it appears "Notification sent with success".

Comment: The message part can't be done inside the particpantRules method since it is a third parameter. The participantRules method will return one and only one thing, an array in your case.

Comment: Don't forget to put the validate method outside of your if statement. If not, it will only validate when send_to is "participant" :)

Comment: Like this? "   public function send(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $conference = Conference::find($id);

        $message = $request->message;
        $subject = $request->subject;
        $emails = [];

        $this->validate(request(), $this->participantRules($id));         if($request->send_to == "participant"){

..."?

Comment: Like that the validation error messages appear. But the email field is only required if the user select "to a specific participant" in the select menu, that is, if the user wants to send a email for a specific participant. Do you know how to correct that? Because like that it appears always that the email is required.

Comment: Maybe have 2 methods like " protected function participantRules(){
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'subject' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required'
        ];
    }

    protected function participantsRules(){
        return [
            'subject' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required'
        ];
    }"?

Comment: I just edited my answer, is it what your were looking for ?

Comment: Thanks, like that it works but to have custom messages is only necessary to add "$messages = [
    'email.email' => 'Your email is invalid',
    'email.required' => 'You must enter an email address',
    'subject.required' => 'You must enter a subject'
];
$this->validate(request(), $this->participantRules($id), $messages);" after "return [
        'email' => 'required_if:send_to,participant|email|nullable',
        'subject' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required'
    ];"?

Comment: To be honnest i didn't really understood what did you mean but to have custom messages, you have multiple options. 

The easiest in your case is to pass a third parameter to the validate method as stated in my answer, so it should look like that: `$this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);`

Keep in mind that you can have messages for rules that don't apply (like email.required_if in the case it is not required). Just write the message and if it is not used, laravel will ignore them.

In your case,write an array with all the rules and messages and it'll be fine :)

Comment: Thanks, like that is not working do you know why? "protected function participantRules($request){
        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required_if:send_to,participant|email|nullable',
            'subject' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required'
        ];

        $customMessages = [
            'email.required_if' => 'The field email is mandatory.',
        'email.email' => 'Invalid email.','subject.required' => 'The field subject is required.', 'message.required' => 'The field message is required.',
        ];$this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);}"

Comment: It shows "Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request".